# UPDATE from SELECT using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2014

My problem is:

I have 2 tables: `Employees` (it has `FirstName`, `LastName` and `EmployeeId` columns) and `ProjectWorkers` (it has `FullName` and `WorkerId`columns).

`WorkerId` is the same as `EmployeeId` so I need to fill `ProjectWorkers.FullName` with joined data from `Employees.FirstName` and `LastName` datas (according to `WorkerId=EmployeeId`).

I have written a query that fill `FullName` column but only with `FirstNames`, however I don't understand how to join `FirstName` and `FullName` (it has to be simply but it is a problem for me).

My query:

```
USE [HRM_MVC_DEV_Test]
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[ProjectWorkers] set
    FullName = FirstName
        FROM [dbo].[Employees] as e
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProjectWorkers] as p
        ON e.EmployeeId = p.WorkerId
GO
```

P.s. Thanks for formatting text, i ll try to do it myself next time )

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please, specify.

Comment: `SET FullName = FirstName + LastName`

Comment: @gofr1 He says MS SQL Server in the title.  Should not be tagged with MYSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `+` or [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) (starting with SQL Server 2012):

```
USE [HRM_MVC_DEV_Test]
GO

UPDATE p
SET FullName = FirstName + ' ' + LastName
FROM [dbo].[ProjectWorkers] as p
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employees] as e
    ON e.EmployeeId = p.WorkerId
GO
```

Another way:

```
SET FullName = CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
       UPDATE ProjectWorkers SET 
       ProjectWorkers.FullName = Employees.FirstName FROM
       ProjectWorkers INNER JOIN Employees ON
       ProjectWorkers.EmployeeId = EmployeesON.EmployeeId
```

Comment: i mean ProjectWorkers.FullName = Employees.FirstName  + ' ' +      Employees.LastName